# .htaccess redirect multiple different "?p=" to specific pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

i have this redirects i´m trying to solve:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /?p=10 /my-first-page
RedirectMatch 301 /?p=20 /my-second-page
RedirectMatch 301 /?p=30 /my-second-page
RedirectMatch 301 /?p=40 /my-third-page
```

Since the redirect doesn´t work this way, because of the `?`, i found this solution for one of them:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=10 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my-first-page? [L,R=301]
```

My question is, can i somehow optimize this to not write this two lines for every redirect i´m trying to make? Can I maybe atleast insert all the pagenumbers (20 & 30) that have to redirect to the same destination-page  using an array?

I might have to do this for about 100 pages, so any optimization is appreciated. Thx for your help.

Comment: You can list alternatives using this pattern syntax, `p=(20|30|…)`

Comment: @CBroe this is a good start, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can i somehow optimize this to not write this two lines for every redirect i´m trying to make?

You can't do this in `.htaccess` alone because there doesn't appear to be any "pattern" that maps this numeric id to destination URL.

(If you have access to the server config then you can create a `RewriteMap` that contains the mapping of ID to URL. This can then be called from `.htaccess`. But I assume you do not have access to the server config here?)

> Can I maybe atleast insert all the pagenumbers (20 & 30) that have to redirect to the same destination-page using an array?

You can certainly do this. Either using alternation (eg. `(20|30|40)`) as @CBroe mentioned in comments, or using some other regex pattern. eg. `[1-4]0` matches `10`, `20`, `30` and `40`.

However, instead of "redirecting" it is probably preferable to *internally rewrite* the request to the same destination page and then use your server-side script to lookup the ID and issue the appropriate external redirect - if a redirect is required.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=(10|20|30|40)$
RewriteRule ^$ redirect-handler.script [L]
```

Note that the `NC` is not required unless you really do need to match both `p` and `P`?

Then in `/redirect-handler.script` you store an array of all the IDs and URLs that should be redirected to and issue an external 3xx redirect as appropriate.

In the above example, the query string, eg. `p=10` is passed through to the target script by default - it doesn't need to be explicitly passed if you are OK using the same URL parameter name in your target script. However, if you wanted to explicitly pass the *value* (perhaps to a different parameter name, such as `id`) then you can modify the above rule like so:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=(10|20|30|40)$
RewriteRule ^$ redirect-handler.script?id=%1 [L]
```

Where `%1` is a backreference to the captured subpattern in the last matched *CondPattern*. ie. Whatever matches `(10|20|30|40)`.

Note that this matches requests of the form `example.com/?p=10` as denoted by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^$` (an empty URL-path).